# In Winform, How to create multiple treeview objects in one form?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, treeview

I tried to create three treeview objects in one form, but only first treeview can display first level nodes, other treeviews are empty.

In addition, the treenodes originally intended to be added to the other treeviews are all added to the first treeview.

While it is normal to create only one treenode.

Can anyone tell me why?

Here is the code:

```
        private void temp2()
        {
            #region Prepare data
            int libraryCount = 5;
            TreeNode[] libraries = new TreeNode[libraryCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < libraryCount; i++)
            {
                TreeNode library = new TreeNode("library" + i);
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    TreeNode itemType = new TreeNode("ItemType" + j);
                    library.Nodes.Add(itemType);
                }
                libraries[i] = library;
            }
            #endregion

            #region Create Three TreeViews 
            TreeView tv = new TreeView();
            tv.Width = 100;
            tv.Height = 300;
            tv.Top = 30;
            tv.Left = 30;
            tv.BeginUpdate();
            tv.Nodes.AddRange(libraries);
            tv.EndUpdate();

            TreeView tv2 = new TreeView();
            tv2.Width = 100;
            tv2.Height = 300;
            tv2.Top = 30;
            tv2.Left = 130;
            tv2.BeginUpdate();
            tv2.Nodes.AddRange(libraries);
            tv2.EndUpdate();

            TreeView tv3 = new TreeView();
            tv3.Width = 100;
            tv3.Height = 300;
            tv3.Top = 30;
            tv3.Left = 230;
            tv3.BeginUpdate();
            tv3.Nodes.AddRange(libraries);
            tv3.EndUpdate();
            #endregion

            #region Create form and add treeviews
            Form form = new Form();
            form.Width = (int)(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width * 0.4);
            form.Height = (int)(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height * 0.5);
            form.Controls.AddRange(new[] { tv, tv2, tv3 });
            //form.Controls.Add(tv3);
            form.Show();
            #endregion

        }
```

[This is the form interface after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p8WL.png)(I don't why I can't post image)

Comment: Why are you creating a form like that in the first place instead of adding a new form class to your project and adding the controls in the designer?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I suspect that you can't add the same `TreeNode` objects to multiple `TreeView` controls. You might have to create separate nodes for each tree. That would be easy to test, so I'll leave it to you to do so.

Comment: I didn't use the designer because I wanted to dynamically create treeview when the program was running

Comment: But why would you want to do that? That's fine if you don't know how many controls or how they will be configured until run time but that doesn't seem to be the case here. You know exactly how many controls you want and how you want them configured so why would you not use the designer?

Comment: @John looks like you have the magic 15 rep pts needed sitting right here!

Comment: @JeremyThompson, as long as the right answer is posted, I'm not concerned with who posts it. That's just the kinda guy I am. ;-) I posted a comment in the first place because I wasn't sure that it was the right solution. I'm fine with the OP determining that it was and posting an answer themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John who commented this question (sorry I don't know how to @ him) very much!

The answer is exactly that I shouldn't add the same TreeNode to multiple TreeView objects. The right thing to do is add each treeview with different treenode array.

Comment: you might want to have John to re-post his comment as an Answer so that you can mark and accept his answer.